# Add OTF Font to HTML2PDF in Laravel 5 with "ensepar/html2pdf": "4.0.6"

Tags: php, laravel-5, html2pdf

I am trying to include a custom font to my laravel 5 project, which I would use to generate a PDF document with HTML2PDF (composer package: "ensepar/html2pdf": "4.0.6").

Here is my code:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','de',true);
$html2pdf->addFont('nexarustsans','bold',__DIR__.'/fonts/nexarustsans.otf');
$html2pdf->setDefaultFont('nexarustsans');
$html2pdf->writeHTML(file_get_contents('sample-doc.html'),false);
$html2pdf->Output(__DIR__.'/pdf/'.time().'.pdf','F');
```

I have generated the `.z`, `.ctg.z`, `.php` files with the http://fonts.snm-portal.com/ tool.

Now when I execute the script, I get an output like this:

```
OTTO€@CFF \‰j§4 .GDEFf? ¼GPOSq€@ L:žGSUBãdãœ ØtOS/2e²£0`cmapñ.ˆä0head°Ì6hheaV„$hmtx¥= dXmaxpVP(namec âRpostÿ¸2 0æþ_<õèÐ4á‰Ð4á‰ÿŠþ± ¶ÿUÿŠÿÒVPVº„ŠXKŠX^2, FBRC@ %Ê ÿ–¶ú “ôÐ &44BJiH€ÈÜ êôô    h   .r   >® .r ì (| ¤ À  ,Ô ,Ô   Copyright © 2014 by Fontfabric. All rights reserved.Nexa Rust SansBlack 011.000;FBRC;NexaRustSans-Black01Nexa Rust Sans Black 01Version 1.000;PS 001.000;hotconv 1.0.70;makeotf.lib2.5.58329 DEVELOPMENTNexaRustSans-Black01Fontfabric LLCFontfabrichttp://fontfabric.com/Copyright © 2014 by Fontfabric. All rights reserved.Nexa Rust Sans Black 01Regular1.000;FBRC;NexaRustSans-Black01Version 1.000;PS 001.000;hotconv 1.0.70;makeotf.lib2.5.58329 DEVELOPMENTNexaRustSans-Black01Fontfabric LLCFontfabrichttp://fontfabric.com/Nexa Rust SansBlack 01ø    ÷öýø*:þð,ô ùæçèéêëìíîïóÿ$ û<�  $&/0289?IKLPUZcdijoñ;Os~„ˆ‘’–˜¢£¥«¬²¼¾¿ÃÈÍÖ×ÜÝâ= >B]txvw|{‚‰Ž‹Œšž›œ±³¶´µºÎÑÏÐ@BFòDE?GHM)F"-%!0.#}¹ü÷&/õ GH»   9àm Aú+()*,@AC[\^™LTQINSKPRJh@(/9~©¬±´¸»Þ#'+37HM[gk~ÇÝ&…ó    " & 0 : ¬!"!.!“!™"""""+"H"`"e%Êÿÿ 0:¡«®´¶»¿à &*.69JP^jnÆØ&€ò    & 0 9 ¬!"!.!!–"""""+"H"`"d%Êÿÿ¶”Qþ/àúàÏàûàÔàmà%àßßßÞøÞÔÞÉÛoh„"$b°ÂÌÖØÚäæ  24TZ\dnpptlrvnöýø*:þð,ô ùóÿ$ û<�  $&/0289?IKLPUZcdijoñ;Os~„ˆ‘’–˜¢£¥«¬²¼¾¿ÃÈÍÖ×ÜÝâ=÷>FM?&EQB-DúKü  ,()*>C@AGB(F^[\]kJxtv|w{}‚Ž‰‹Œžš›œ…±¶³´ºµ¹ÑÎÏÐÞ½àyuz€ƒ†‡Š!“#•"”%—- .¡+™'Ÿ1¤3¦5¨4§6©7ª:­<�¯;®=°E¸D·H»MÀOÂNÁQÄSÆRÅXËWÊVÉ`ÓbÕ_ÒaÔfÙlßmpãråqäTÇYÌLJINSRTPhÛeØgÚná @Aò465178320'%!ÿµ2NexaRustSans-Black01&øøœøøû ûãú¡ªHµ ƒ!+17=GNU[gquwˆ›¡§³·½ÃÏÒßæìòþ"*6CJQV\gpv‡—¤«±·ÁÇÍÓÝäëñý%17=IMSYehu|‚ˆ”š¢®²¸ÀÌÙàçìòý#-:HLWcks|„‹’›¤±...........
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? o.O